# Should I write a recommendation for my replacement on the resignation letter?

Tags: resignation, germany, replacement

Say that I'd like to quit my job because I found another one, I'd have to (goes without saying) write a resignation letter.
Imagine now that I happen to know the perfect candidate to replace me (has worked with me for some time, has some of my know-how, etc.).

Should I want to go good by this guy and my company (I really think it would be win-win for both), should I recommend him to fill my position on the resignation letter?

I'm looking for:

- A "cultural" answer (the company is in Germany)
- A "professional" answer (is this professional/unprofessional?)
- Possible outcome of the letter (would HR even consider that?)

Comment: "never give advice unless asked" a German proverb.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The letter of resignation in Germany usually only contains the most basic facts: "I am resigning my position effective this date."  No explanations, no apologies, no kerfuffel, just that (the written notice should be given to HR).

For making a recommendation about a replacement candidate, I would just speak to my manager about this (provided you are leaving on good terms with that person) when I gave them the news I was going to leave, which I always do in person.